# Sending a full Transcript, or only a part?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, transcript-of-records

I have a quick question. I have to send in official transcripts to some graduate schools. I am trying to apply for Mathematics. However, since i am also doing a B.A in Philosophy and Economics, the last semester has no mathematics classes as I have some classes I have to take. I have the option to not disclose that in my official transcript and "cut off" the future semester. Would that be seen as disingenuous? I don't want the admissions to think I am "avoiding" mathematics, there is sim ply no math courses my school offers that I would like to take and I need some courses for my other majors.

Comment: Send in the full transcript. Just because there's a semester of no math doesn't mean they'll look down on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just one advise: Be honest. Changing an official transcript to make you look better is not honest, and could get you into trouble.

Moreover, a semester without math does not necessarily look bad.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the lack of more advanced courses in your undergraduate program could be a point of discussion in your letter or essay? I agree with Sean Roberson -- send the entire transcript. If you were judged alongside another applicant and you each have equivalent maths coursework, the advanced courses in Philosophy or Economics may make you more appealing/interesting.

Have you reached out to the administrators and/or faculty in some of the departments to which you are applying? You can ask them their opinion on this, and other things. You could remain anonymous, or not. There's not much to lose and potentially a lot to gain by asking them these questions. Good luck!